# HTML/JS: Delete a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, html

I want to delete a html form. Whats the best way to do this?

Is it using javascript? I'm going to have several forms with text and a delete(submit) button on each form, and a javascript to confirm deletion. Does anyone have any suggestions or links to good informative sites? I've tried google and W3S but haven't found anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "delete" do you mean "clear the fields to default values"?

Comment: Delete as in remove from the DOM?

Comment: I'm new but i think as remove from DOM? Not just clear values. I have a form with fieldset and legend. I want it all to be removed. Thanks

Comment: Removed from the DOM completely or just hidden from the view of the user?

Comment: Removed. It's comments that should be removed and not just hidden. Thanks

Comment: Sort of off-topic:
Speaking of W3Schools, you should check out this site: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Thanks nix, just scrolled through it fast. I will definitely check the other recommended sites. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without `jQuery`, using `DOM`:

```
function Remove(form_id) {
    if (window.confirm('Remove this form?')) {
        var f = document.getElementById(form_id);
        f.parentNode.removeChild(f);
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
onclick="Remove('form_id')"
```

Comment: BTW, you can use this to delete **ANY** object under `body` tag.

Comment: +1 for providing a non-jQuery solution, however I would prefer if the remove button had an ID that could be used, instead of adding an onclick event to it.

Comment: @Nix sorry, I didn't get your point, really bad english of mine.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, and it seems to work. But everytime I confirm deletion the form the returns, i think the page is reloaded and the hardcoded form is rendered again.. Can someone confirm this? HTML CODE: http://pastebin.com/cYsMCWbP

Comment: @Mr.Havoc you have to use this function in the event `onclick` of any object but `submit`!! However if you really want to use this way, change your `onsubmit` to this: `onsubmit="Remove(id); return false;"` and your `form` will not be submited!!

Comment: Ok, well I'm taking this webbdevelopment course at uni and the teacher has given us instructions and the button here should be a submit... We're going to get information from a database, maybe it will be rendered properly when the comment is deleted from database, and not hardcoded in like now. Thanks

Comment: +1 For supplying a JavaScript answer (not jQuery) to a JavaScript question.

Comment: @Márcio: Minor detail really, I just don't like mixing javascript and markup. I find it's much better to asign an ID to the button, then use that ID to run the function from your JS-file.

Comment: @Nix, right, now I got it. As do I either, but in this case that is too much simpler, I think there's no problem, but I agee with you. Some times is better to is an ID.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.detach` or `.remove` of jQuery ..

```
$(function(){
      $('#button').click(function(){
              if ( confirm ( 'Remove this form ?' ) ) {
                    $('#form').remove()
              }
      });
});
```